# Acer Aspire V5-131 hard disk clicking

Tags: hard-drive, acer, aspire

I bought a machine Acer Aspire v5-131 Intel Celeron 1017U. Everything is working great, found quickly how to fix not working brightness regulation. But was unable to solve hard disk clicking problem (occurs every 1-3 sec). I have only one partition (`/`), no `swap`.

I tried doing the following solutions found on the net:

```
sudo hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda or sudo hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda
```

Neither did stop the clicking. And: `gedit /etc/hdparm.conf`:

```
 
 /dev/sda {
    apm = 254 #(or 255)
    apm_battery = 254 "(or 255)
}
```

The problem does not occur on Windows 7/8 at all (although I removed them completely). Ubuntu stops the clicking after I connect the power cord.

Thanks in advance, if anyone knows the solution.

Tried standard 64 bit version 13.04 and XFCE, the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: When dealing with possible physical hardware issues with hard drive, make sure that you have a current backup just to be on the safe side.** You may want to take a look at [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Clicking noises from a HDD are usually the beginning of a drive failure. The clicking is the internal mechanism attempting to access the drive and being physically unable to properly mechanically engage the position for reading.

Now a little on the bright side, I have had this happen before with a Seagate drive.  It has to to with power management on the drive.  I updated the firmware, and that fixed it.  See if the drive manufacturer has a firmware update on their website.

In case the firmware update doen't fix it, make sure that you backup the drive just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I have the V5-131 too. This clicking isn't the hard disk, its caused by the power saving option of the sounddriver: http://www.foxswap.com/computers-and-technology/ubuntu-12-04-clicking-sound-from-speakers/

Comment: Whilst this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.